# ArrayList, метод addAll

Tags: java, android

```
private ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> newArr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.addAll(newArr);
```

Объясните, что происходит внутри?

Comment: Внутрь лучше не смотреть, чтобы не разочаровываться в создателях Java.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью метода `addAll(...)` можно добавить элементы одной коллекцию в другую.

Но в данном конкретном случае происходит только ерунда, так как:

- приведенный код (в таком виде, в котором он есть) даже не скомпилируется;
- здесь происходит добавление элементов **пустой** коллекции в другую коллекцию.

А если смотреть прямо *внутрь*, то метод `addAll(...)` имеет две реализации:

- `public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`
- `public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`

А если захотите, то можно посмотреть очень глубоко [*внутрь*](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

**UPD.**

> Меня интересует добавление одной коллекции в другую. Можете пример привести?

Могу:

```
ArrayList<String> firstArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
firstArrayList.add("1");
firstArrayList.add("2");
firstArrayList.add("3");

ArrayList<String> secondArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
secondArrayList.addAll(firstArrayList);
```

В результате этих манипуляций `secondArrayList` будет содержать те три элемента, которые находятся в `firstArrayList`.

Comment: Меня интересует добавление одной коллекции в другую.Можете пример привести?

Comment: @MartinezToni, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: если в secondArrayList уже есть какие-то элементы и мы используем метод addAll, то новыые элементы приписываются в конец?

Comment: @MartinezToni, В данном случае – да. Но в общем случае можно указать номер элемента, начиная с которого будет происходить запись.

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял вы в `arr` добавили всё что находиться в `newArr`.